# Basic php process for html

Tags: php, html

When using this php process for html forms I only get a response of just "Hello, ". Here is  a link to where I have the file uploaded maybe it is a problem on my end break.hostoi.com  the php code it self

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["$name"];
    echo "Hello, " . $name;
?>
```

and here is the html if needed

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
    Enter your name' <input name="name" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

```
$name = $_POST["$name"];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

the dollar sign shouldn't be in there

```
["$name"]
  ^-- // remove this
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// rest of code
```

Having done this, would've thrown an error similar to this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in...(path of file)  on line X

To learn more on error reporting, visit:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also, go through the PHP.net website. http://php.net

You can browse through their website where examples are shown. No better way to start than in the manuals themselves.

PHP forms on PHP.net

- http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

---

***Footnotes:***

Also, you are open to [**XSS attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (Cross-site scripting).

Use the following (PHP) filter function: [`FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

```
$name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

> Equivalent to calling [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with `ENT_QUOTES` set. Encoding quotes can be disabled by setting.

---

**Edit:**

As per Jeremy1026's comment:

*"by doing `$_POST["$name"]` you are basically doing, `$name = foo; $_POST['foo'];`"*

Thank you for the additional comment in order to improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for that simple fix! I just started php today so basics here we go.

Comment: Additional note on this already good answer, by doing `$_POST["$name"]` you are basically doing, `$name = foo; $_POST['foo'];`

Comment: @Jeremy1026 Thanks, I will add it, credited to you, cheers. +1