# How to discover if today's date is between 2 other dates?

Tags: php, if-statement

I can't quite get the syntax right, I just need an IF statement to check if today is between a set of dates and if so, echo.  How should this be tweaked?

```
$now = time('Y/m/d');
$date_september = '2014/09/01';
$date_october = '2014/10/01'; 

if ($now > $date_september && $now < $date_october) 
{
    echo "do this...";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `DateTime()`. It makes date comparisons easier as those objects are comparable.
2. Your `if` statement is invalid. PHP doesn't support any shorthand syntax for comparisons.

Try this;

```
$now            = new DateTime();
$date_september = new DateTime('2014-09-01');
$date_october   = new DateTime('2014-10-01'); 
if ($now > $date_september && $now < $date_october) {
    echo "do this...";
}
```

Comment: Yahhhhhh care to explain? Garsh, I'm equally astonished!

Comment: You'd be next in line for the "Father Time" position ;)

Comment: I think we've got us a rogue (drive-by) downvoter; just got one now. Hmph! for this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/24976351/

Comment: Wow. Home run with that answer. +1 should negate the unecessary downvote.

Comment: Thanks John. I have **no** freakin' idea as to why some knock off would DV it. Just another drive-by in my eye. Meh~

Comment: I just spent the better part of 2 days trying to figure out where I was going wrong in my script to see if something was older than 24 hours. Your answer John helped me a lot, however, I ended up using something to the effect of `$end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day ago'));` using 2 rows in a `while` loop. Gawd, these things can get so complicated sometimes. *Signed: Pitbull*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Glad this was helpful. It's always good to hear when something you posted helped someone else. Definitely puts a smile on my face :)

Comment: @JohnConde Always nice to see people smile :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to compare the unix timestamp values.  strtotime converts a text date to a unix timestamp (integer) which is the same as what a time() call returns.

```
$now = time();
$date_september = strtotime('2014/09/01');
$date_october = strtotime('2014/10/01'); 

if ($now > $date_september && $now < $date_october) {
    echo "do this...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler solution would be:

```
$now = date('Y/m/d');
$date_september = '2014/09/01';
$date_october = '2014/10/01'; 

if ($now > $date_september && $now < $date_october) {
    echo "do this...";
}
```